# Is there a way to send a flash notice through a button_to form in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have the following in my view:

```
<br><%= button_to "Go on this ride", user_path(@user), method: :get %>
```

And I want to pass a flash notice through to a view in another controller with this logic:

```
 if @ride.take_ride
   flash[:notice] = "Thank you for riding #{@attraction.name}!"
 end
```

Which is based on this logic in my model:

```
class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attraction

  def take_ride
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    @attraction = Attraction.find(attraction_id)
    can_ride?(@user, @attraction)
  end

  def can_ride?(user, attraction)
    if attraction.tickets > user.tickets && attraction.min_height > user.height
      "Sorry. You do not have enough tickets the #{@attraction.name}. You are not tall enough to ride the #{@attraction.name}."
    elsif attraction.tickets > user.tickets 
      enough_tickets?
    elsif attraction.min_height > user.height
      tall_enough?
    else
      update_user(user, attraction)
    end
  end

  def tall_enough?
    "Sorry. You are not tall enough to ride the #{@attraction.name}."
  end

  def enough_tickets?
    "Sorry. You do not have enough tickets the #{@attraction.name}."
  end

  def update_user(user, attraction)
    user.tickets = user.tickets - attraction.tickets
    user.nausea = user.nausea + attraction.nausea_rating
    user.happiness = user.happiness + attraction.happiness_rating
    user.save
  end
end
```

Is it possible to pass a flash message through my button_to form, and if not, how can I pass this message through?

Comment: your code should run where is the problem u are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

`button_to` follows to controller action
and in controller you can set the flash message

Comment: The controller may not have the knowledge to create the appropriate flash. This is the problem.